# How to attend several request in parallel with twisted Klein

Tags: python, api, asynchronous, twisted

I am creating an API to execute command line commands. The server has only two methods practically, "run" and "stop". So, the main function of "run" is to run a command line program in the server side and return a list with the system output. For the other hand, the function of "stop" just kill the process running. Here is the code:

```
import sys
import json
import subprocess

from klein import Klein


class ItemStore(object):
    app = Klein()
    current_process = None

    def __init__(self):
        self._items = {}

    def create_process(self, exe):
        """
        Run command and return the system output inside a JSON string
        """
        print("COMMAND: ", exe)
        process = subprocess.Popen(exe, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                   stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        self.current_process = process

        # Poll process for new output until finished
        output_lines = []

        counter = 0
        while True:
            counter = counter + 1
            nextline = process.stdout.readline()

            if process.poll() is not None:
                break

            aux = nextline.decode("utf-8")

            output_lines.append(aux)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            counter = counter + 1

        print("RETURN CODE: ", process.returncode)
        return json.dumps(output_lines)

    @app.route('/run/<command>', methods=['POST'])
    def run(self, request, command):
        """
        Execute command line process
        """
        exe = command
        print("COMMAND: ", exe)

        output_lines = self.create_process(exe)

        request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        request.setResponseCode(200)
        return output_lines

    @app.route('/stop', methods=['POST'])
    def stop(self, request):
        """
        Kill current execution
        """
        self.current_process.kill()

        request.setResponseCode(200)
        return None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    store = ItemStore()
    store.app.run('0.0.0.0', 15508)
```

Well, the problem with this is, if I need to stop the current execution, "stop" request will be not attend until "run" request has finished, so it has no sense to work in this way. I have been reading several pages about async/await solution, but I can not get it work!. I think the most prominent solution is in this webpage https://crossbario.com/blog/Going-Asynchronous-from-Flask-to-Twisted-Klein/ , however, "run" is still a synchronous process. I just posted my main and original code in order to not confuse with the webpage changes.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Everything to do with Klein in this example is already handling requests concurrently.  However, your application code blocks until it has fully responded to a request.

You have to write your application code to be non-blocking instead of blocking.

Switch your code from the subprocess module to [Twisted's process support](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/process.html).

Use [Klein's feature of being able to return a Deferred instead of a result](https://klein.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/deferreds.html) (if you want incremental results while the process is running, also look at [the request interface](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.iweb.IRequest.html) - in particular, the `write` method - so you can [write those results](https://twisted.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web/howto/web-in-60/asynchronous.html) before the Deferred fires with a final result).

After Deferreds make sense to you, then you might want to think about syntactic sugar that's available in the form of async/await.  *Until* you understand what Deferreds are doing, async/await is just going to be black magic that will only ever work by accident in your programs.

Comment: Hello there, I have already tried using Deferred but the code is still blocked. Could you show me what to change at my code? When I have to use await keyword the code block the request (logically).

Comment: I don't plan to rewrite your code so that it works.  "already tried using Deferred" doesn't tell me much.  What about the rest of the answer?  Did you try using Request.write?  Did you try using reactor.spawnProcess?

Comment: I known I am losing just a few keyword over the code, I have just asked that, but well, I have already tried a lot of combinations with the links you provided and still the codes block the execution.